# Train own object detector with opencv

Tags: opencv

I am in Linux with OpenCV 3.0 Alpha

I search alot on the web on training own object detector

But when i follow some instruction, it doesnt work on me. Here's my situtation:

First I download 550 positive samples in 100px width and 40px height

and i also got 550 negative samples in 100px width and 40px height

then create the positives.info and negatives.txt

I am sure the info file and txt file are in correct content and the images are nice enough

then I create sample vec file:

```
opencv_createsamples -info positives.info -num 550 -w 48 -h 24 -vec cars.vec
```

and it comes out:

```
Info file name: positives.info
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: cars.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 550
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 48
Height: 24
Create training samples from images collection...
Done. Created 550 samples
```

It seems ok with the 550 samples,

then i train the cascade:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec cars.vec -bg negatives.txt -numPos 500 -numNeg 500 -numStages 2 -w 48 -h 24 -featureType LBP
```

### and it comes :

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: data
vecFileName: cars.vec
bgFileName: negatives.txt
numPos: 500
numNeg: 500
numStages: 2
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 48
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   500 : 500
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    500 : 1
Precalculation time: 0
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|    0.414|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 3 seconds.

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   500 : 500
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    500 : 0.578035
Precalculation time: 0
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|     0.46|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 6 seconds.
```

And i found the cascade.xml

so I test it, I just use the face detect provided by the opencv, but i use my own cascade file.

but i comes out the blue rectangle box which should mark up the car but just

draw right in the middle of the image. I test positive image and negative image, it just

draw a rectangle in the middle.

which step i gone wrong? and how do i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the training parameters. NumberofStages should increase , also you can use HAAR as a featureType , and you can set minhitrate and maxfalselarm rate.